# sql stored procedure return value

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure

bonjour, 
when executing a stored procedure, i have got my result and a return value with 0, i know that 0 seem to be no error when executing,
but, i dont wanted that.

[return value 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeSyj.png)

here is my code, where or how can i solve that please?

```
USE [Active]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[PS_BR_listeProjetUneEntreprise]Script Date: 11/04/2018 13:39:10 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
  -- =============================================
  -- Author:        BR
  -- Create date: 11/04/2018
  -- Description:   liste des projets d'une entreprise donnée
  -- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PS_BR_listeProjetUneEntreprise] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@nomClient varchar(55)
AS
BEGIN
  -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
  -- interfering with SELECT statements.
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- Insert statements for procedure here
  select [dbo].[PROJET].nomProjet, [dbo].[CLIENT].raisonSociale
  from [dbo].[PROJET]
  join [dbo].[CLIENT]
  on [dbo].[PROJET].idClient = [dbo].[CLIENT].idClient
  where [dbo].[CLIENT].raisonSociale like @nomClient
END
```

i am using sql server management studio 17

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Use a table valued functions.  Using stored procedures to return result sets should be a last resort.

Comment: If you don't want `0`, what do you want?

Comment: 0 is just it returned your values. What do you want ?

Comment: For returning single scalar values, [don't use `RETURN`, use `OUTPUT`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-or-return-instead-of-output).  "I don't want to" isn't a very technical reason to break convention.

Comment: i dont want the return value, is it possible?

Comment: Where are you seeing the return value that you don't want it? Please describe your problem better. Calling this procedure, as is, does not produce this `Return Value` column you're showing in SSMS. That must be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: You're screenshot is showing at least 3 columns but the stored procedure is only returning two.  Are you looking at the wrong stored proc?

Comment: To return just the result set, run this from an SSMS query window: `EXEC dbo.PS_BR_listeProjetUneEntreprise @nomClient = 'YourClientName';`.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the output image, I feel like you are executing your SP using `SSMS` like below query.

```
USE [Active]
GO    
DECLARE @return_value INT
DECLARE @nomClient varchar(55) ='abc'    
EXECUTE @return_value = [dbo].[PS_BR_listeProjetUneEntreprise] @nomClient    
SELECT  @return_value
```

Above is the standard template used when you use generate script option for executing a SP.

You can run it without return value also like following.

```
USE [Active]
GO    
DECLARE @nomClient varchar(55) ='abc'
EXECUTE  [dbo].[PS_BR_listeProjetUneEntreprise] @nomClient
```

This way you will not get additional record.

Comment: i will try, thanx you